# Express-jwt controle token before route

Tags: node.js, express-jwt

My api always checks the validity of the token first and foremost and therefore always returns 401 even if the route does not exist, if the token is good it checks the route and returns a 404 if the route does not exist at that time.

It shouldn't be the other way around first a route existence test and then the token test ?

How to implement this ?

```
app.use(expressJwt({  secret: process.env.SECRET_TOKEN }).unless({ path: [
        '/api/login'
    ]}));
app.use(errorHandler)

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if(err.status === '401') { // partie api PP avec token
        res.status(401).json({returnCode: 100, returnLabel: 'KO', data:{}});
        return;
    }else if(err.status === '404'){
        res.status(404).json({returnCode: 404, returnLabel: '404', data:{}});
        return;
    }else { 
        res.status(500)
        res.json({error: err})
    }
}
```

Moreover I can not catch the 404 in my condition yet I have a return like this not in errorHandler like 401 :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /V1/</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found the solution myself, I had to add this in my code :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.status(404);
   res.json({returnCode: 404, returnLabel: '404: File Not Found', data:{}});
return;
});
```

in addition to my errorHandler already in place.(apparently a 404 does not trigger an error and will not fit in the handler)

Otherwise, I can't find an answer if a REST API must check the token or the path first ?